# Microsoft C++ Library Symbol Linkage At Build Time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

Using Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express:

I am trying to perform the final link step in a build compiled as follows:

- A library `foo.lib` is statically compiled (the build does not produce a `.dll`) with the `/MD` switch. The build for `foo.lib` succeeds. The `.lib` file and headers are shipped to a directory where the project for the below library can find them. `foo.lib` sources are written in unmanaged C++.
- A library `bar.dll` is compiled as a dynamic library with the `/MD /LD` switches. `bar.dll` depends on `foo.lib` exported symbols. Both `bar.dll` and `foo.lib` are built form source using the same `cl.exe` and `link.exe` binaries from the VS2008 Express toolchain. `bar.dll` sources are written in unmanaged C++.
- All the `.obj` files of `bar.dll` build successfully, but during the final execution of `link.exe` that would produce `bar.dll`, I receive **thousands** of `LNK2001` errors about undefined externals. All of the undefined externals are things that I would expect to be in a standard C++ library: things like `std::basic_string` constructors, the `std::_Throw` class, `ostream` overloaded operators, and on and on. `link.exe` says that the undefined externals **are undefined within `foo.lib`!**
- The goal is for `bar.dll` to contain the entire statically linked code of `foo.lib` within it, as well as its own objects, but dynamically depend on the existence/resolution of `MSVCR90.dll` and `MSVCP90.dll` at runtime.

Am I trying to set up an impossible situation with this build, or am I just doing something wrong? If this can't work at all in theory, let me know. Otherwise, please let me know what diagnostics I could try to determine why the C++ library symbols are not available to `foo.lib` during the final link step.

**Edit**: More specific information: `foo.lib` is [LLVM](http://llvm.org) 3.1 and `bar.dll` is the `libgl-gdi` (`llvmpipe`) build of [Mesa](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa) from the `master` branch (the goal is to produce `opengl32.dll` that runs on `llvmpipe`). I have satisfied all the build dependencies as follows:

- LLVM build depends on [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) as the build system, and Python 2.7.
- Mesa build depends on [SCons](http://www.scons.org) as the build system, LLVM 2.6 or later, Python 2.7, pywin32, python-libxml2, bison, and flex. Out of the above, only LLVM gets shipped around at runtime; the rest are just "tools" used during the build process.

I have also customized the build for each project as appropriate to set environment variables and ensure that they are consistently using only the `/MD` switch and not `/MT` or some other switch for selecting a wrong C runtime library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Defines **_MT** and **_DLL** so that both multithread- and DLL-specific versions of the run-time routines are selected from the standard .h files. This option also causes the compiler to place the library name MSVCRT.lib into the .obj file.
>   Applications compiled with this option are statically linked to MSVCRT.lib. This library provides a layer of code that allows the linker to resolve external references. The actual working code is contained in MSVCR71.DLL, which must be available at run time to applications linked with MSVCRT.lib.
>
> When /MD is used with _STATIC_CPPLIB defined (/D_STATIC_CPPLIB) it will cause the application to link with the static multithread Standard C++ Library (libcpmt.lib) instead of the dynamic version (msvcprt.lib) while still dynamically linking to the main CRT via msvcrt.lib.

More specifically - this excerpt: "*Applications compiled with this option are statically linked to MSVCRT.lib*"

In other words - you *need* to link your foo.lib to msvcrt.lib.

Comment: So are you saying that just specifying `/MD` is not equivalent to adding `msvcrt.lib` to the build path, and that I manually have to do this myself? I want the "stub" `msvcrt.lib` to be included within `foo.lib` so that the external symbols resolve, but I don't want the entire *implementation* of the C runtime to be built into my binary, because I am shipping the DLLs already with my larger project, so it would waste disk space.

Comment: By the way, I agree that I *need* to link `foo.lib` to `msvcrt.lib`. That's what I'm trying to do, but I thought `/MD` did that. If not, I need to know how to link it. The build system for `foo.lib` produces a Visual Studio solution with projects as normal, but the build system for `bar.dll` does not, so I'll have to resort to other means if I have to touch the `bar.dll` build.

Comment: `fool.lib` imports symbols from `msvcrt.lib` so any binary that links in `foo.lib` would have to link-in the `msvcrt.lib` as well. The only magic `/MD` does is, and I quote from the answer's quote, `Defines _MT and _DLL so that both multithread- and DLL-specific versions of the run-time routines are selected from the standard .h files`, i.e. **only affecting the compilation**

Comment: Thanks, I never figured out the solution to my problem, but ended up compiling with MinGW instead.

Comment: Damn you can't do this to me! I need your solution! =)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common point of confusion with visual studio projects.

/MD doesn't build a static library. That is a flag that can be used with any binary output from visual studio (lib, dll, exe). It merely means you're telling your binary to use the static CRT (C runtime). This is, in the common case, the wrong choice and you will get link issues when linking into applications or DLL's that do NOT statically link the CRT (using the DYNAMIC CRT).

Have a look here for more information:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

There should be a setting under the project settings under Configuration Properties/General/Configuration type. That should be what you're using to determine what kind of binary you're building

Comment: I thought `/MD` was to tell the binary to use the *dynamic* CRT? It just puts a simple "stub" library `MSVCRT.lib` into the compiled .lib. The stub doesn't contain the actual implementation of the C library, it only provides runtime linkage to the .dll file.

Comment: @cppguy:  `/MD` says to build assuming you'll get the dynamic C and C++ runtime libraries at the final link, which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample that does what you're trying to do.

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

extern void print_foo();

#endif
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>

void print_foo() {
  std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}
```

Build foo.cpp into a static library that will depend on the dynamic run-time libraries:

```
cl /c /MD /EHsc foo.cpp
lib foo.obj
```

bar.h:

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#ifdef BAR_DLL
#define BARAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define BARAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

BARAPI void print_bar();

#endif
```

bar.cpp:

```
#include "bar.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

BARAPI void print_bar() {
  std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
  print_foo();
}
```

Build bar.cpp into a DLL that pulls in code from foo.lib and depends in the dynamic runtime libraries:

```
cl /c /MD /EHsc /DBAR_DLL bar.cpp
link /DLL bar.obj foo.lib
```

And a simple main.cpp to show that it works:

```
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
  print_bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Build it like this:

```
cl /c /MD /EHsc main.cpp
link main.obj bar.lib
```

(The runtime libraries should come in automatically because the /MD options should have tagged the object files as needing the dynamic runtime libraries.)

main.exe output:

```
bar
foo
```